# MYSQL commands and phpmyadmin backup scheduled task

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, concatenation, mysql-backup

```
set @file = CONCAT ('
-u root tableName>/backup/tableName', CURRENT_DATE(), '.sql'
)
mysqldump @file
```

is resulting in an error in syntax.

I just want to dump a backup - every day - labeled with the current date.

but I'm a mysql noob and I have been hunting for the correct syntax long enough I thought that I would ask...

Comment: you an not run a shell command from a browser or in mysql

Comment: the command is in a trigger on phpmyadmin set to noon of every day.
you are correct that it is not in a shell command. must it be?

Comment: mysqldump is a shell comand you can only dump data with SELECT outfile

Comment: can i use the trigger to trigger a php shell script then?

Comment: i don't know any possibility, with a plugin ti run a command., a trigger will execute every time a row changes get inserted or deleted, that is not the right command. What you have to do is see how your oprating system makes tasks and scheule one that runs the mysqldump

Comment: In Windows, create a batch file and use Windows scheduler to fire it when required. Under linux, use a cron task.